# Does editing a question push it to the top of the newest questions list?

Tags: support, edits, newest-questions

Just been following a question where the OP added a new post with the same question rephrased, which is I believe frowned upon. I'm just about to suggest he edits his original question by adding clarifications, more detail etc, and to explain that this action refreshes his question in the list, but just wanted someone to confirm for me that this is actually the case.

Comment: Can you show the question?

Comment: This is the orginalnquestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696649/notification-when-wpf-ui-closes

Comment: And this is the second: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734483/open-wpf-settings-window-from-forms-app

Comment: As I suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149419/187824) If you think the question is duplicate, you can flag duplicate question as exact duplicate.

Comment: In this particular case, I don't think there's any need to flag the second question as a duplicate, as both questions have now been answered and accepted (the OP actually posted his own answer to his original question, based on the accepted answer to the second question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does editing a question push it to the top of the newest questions list?

No. It doesn't. But it push it to the top of [Active questions list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active)

If OP added a new post with the same question rephrased, you can flag it as exact duplicate of his/her original question. And add a comment to a new post to edit original post instead of adding new one.

Comment: Just for Note : Even editing old answer or adding new answer to old question can put it in **Active** list.

Comment: @Lucifer Yes. *Active questions list* means **Active Post list**. And post can be an answer or a question. :)